# 2 Windows server 2012 with multiple domain

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

I would like to ask regarding some setup and configuration for windows 2012 server. The situation as below :

1) I have 1 wan ip / public ip
2) I have 2 windows server 2012 (server1,server2)
3) I have 2 domain with internal ip belong to themself in the same network (domain1,domain2)

Workflow situation :

- Currently i already setup dns only in server1. no onther service like active domain directory or etc.
- domain1 point to server1
- public ip point to server1

What i want to do :

- domain2 point to server2
- how can i use the same public ip to point to server2?

Comment: You're talking about two web servers, right?

Comment: Yup any idea  @EvanAnderson

Answer (score 1):

You can't, at least not directly.  But you can:

- Get a second IP address
- Run the second webserver on a different port (so users have to go to http://example2.com:81)
- Proxy one webserver to the other - using name based hosting on the publicly accessible server to relay requests to the other server - this increases the load on that server and adds another point of failure
- Run both sites on the same machine
- Put in a load balancer type appliance that will direct requests to the right server - it will be the one publicly accessible and can inspect HTTP requests and direct them to the right server.

Comment: I know the solution can be faster by getting second ip address. But actually how the hosting company manage to do it @Grant

Comment: @muhamadazam added a bunch more options (I actually wasn't done hit submit early by accident)

Comment: It will be much, much less complicated and not very expensive to just get a 2nd IP address. Running both sites on the same machine would be the 2nd best option for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for the input. I manage to get it done by using 1 IP.

Do the trick by adding the domain in the in the forward lookout zone .

Next, put the pointer to the second server in the reverse lookout zone to the domain i put in the forward lookout zone.

It works like a charm.